# how to configure epstopdf in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, epstopdf

I have a problem with an eps figure in latex.

When I try to compile my document I get this error:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `BD-SDS1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.741 ...{40mm}{!}{\includegraphics{BD-SDS1.eps}}}
Using draft setting for this image.
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
LaTeX Warning: File `PCA-AWSPCA-p1.eps' not found on input line 788.
```

I think this is a problem related to the epstopdf package. 
I have already installed the full version of tex live. So maybe I am missing something.

I also tried these command :

```
donbeo@donbeo-K56CM:~$ echo $TEXINPUTS

donbeo@donbeo-K56CM:~$ sudo apt-get install texlive-font-utils
[sudo] password for donbeo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive-font-utils is already the newest version.
texlive-font-utils set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb openjdk-7-jre-lib
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
donbeo@donbeo-K56CM:~$ ^C
donbeo@donbeo-K56CM:~$
```

Comment: Exactly which version of TeX Live are you using? Is the restricted shell escape enabled in the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @daleif can you please explain me a little better how to do this? I am very new to latex.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Do you mean that I should remove all the latex softwares and installed packages and then reinstall Tex live from software center?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, are you really suggesting that @Donbeo install TeX Live via software center? Because that woulod just end up with the same installation as with `apt-get`. Either install TL proper i.e., the TUG TeXLive or try installing the full Ubuntu TeX Live i.e., `texlive-full`. This is why I asked for your Ubuntu version. The newest Ubuntu have TeX Live 2013 or something like that.

Comment: @daleif Things must have changed then. The last time I looked at it, the apt-get install was much more limited. Better to ignore my advice.

Comment: @daleif I am using the last ubuntu version.

Comment: @Donbeo, then try to install `texlive-full` before you start uninstalling stuff. Problem is that TeX Live on Ubuntu is split up into lots and lots of packages. `texlive-full` installs ALL of them (woth a try). BTW: do you mind updating your question with a MWE such that we can see your preamble.

Comment: Something of mysterious append. I removed all the latex related software and the I installed first texlive-full and then tex-maker. Now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am throwing in my two cents with similar situation. (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, TeXMaker 3.2, texlive-full 2009-15)

Texmaker is throwing up the error as well, "file not found" but the line before the error indicates runsystem(epstopdf...) is disabled:

```
runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=eps/tig-inf-ill-age3-eps-converted-to.pdf eps/tig-inf-ill-age3.eps)...disabled.
```

@daleif you may be right, i am going to try to enable it and see what happens.

UPDATE: Yup,  -shell-escape in the command for PDFLatex solves the issue. In Texmaker -> Options -> Configure Texmaker -> Commands -> PDFLatex: add "-shell-escape", see my line now.

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```